# How to Instantiate new HTMLElement?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to instantiate new HTMLDivElement in TypeScript

```
var elem = new HTMLDivElement();
```

but the browser throws

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor.
```

The workaround seems to be to use

```
var elem = document.createElement('div');
```

but I find this suboptimal for various reasons.

Why can't I instantiate DOM elements directly when there is a **new** keyword for in in the **lib.d.ts**?

```
declare var HTMLDivElement: {
    prototype: HTMLDivElement;
    new (): HTMLDivElement;
}
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Note that the error you get here is "Illegal constructor". This is different from the error "object is not a function" that you would get if you were to write `new {}()`, for example.

So, technically, `HTMLDivElement` *does* have a constructor. It's just that this particular constructor throws an exception rather than creating an object.

Normally `lib.d.ts` would just exclude such useless signatures, but TypeScript requires that the right-hand side of the `instanceof` operator have a constructor. In other words, it's legal to write `foo instanceof HTMLElement`, but not `foo instanceof []`, and the difference is determined by the fact that `HTMLElement` has a constructor.

There were basically three choices on the table here:

1. Remove the construct signature from the DOM elements and remove the restriction on `instanceof`'s right operand. This is undesirable because you'd really prefer to catch errors where someone accidentally writes code like `x instanceof foo` instead of `x instanceof Foo` (where `foo` is an instance of `Foo`).
2. Remove the construct signature from DOM elements, but keep the `instanceof` check in place. This is bad because `foo instanceof HTMLElement` is a very reasonable thing to write.
3. The current situation, where the constructors exist but you have to know not to call them.

You can't construct DOM elements using normal constructors because you're supposed to go through `document.createElement`. This is basically for technical reasons relating to how browsers implement these objects.

Comment: Amazing explanation. Would it be possible to have a comment in lib.d.ts explaining this? Or you don't want to pollute lib.d.ts with comments?

Comment: Would it make sense to add a warning or error from `tsc` for code that invokes constructors on subclasses of `Element`?

Comment: If you extend HTMLElement, for example `class Thing extends HTMLElement` then you CAN use new to create an instance with `let t = new Thing()`. Then you can add it to the DOM!

Comment: This appears not to be the case, Kokodoko: `class Thing extends HTMLElement {} `; `let t = new Thing()` results in `TypeError: Illegal constructor.`

Comment: `customElements.define( 'custom-tag', Thing );` then call `new Thing()` - which returns `<custom-tag></custom-tag>`

Comment: notice there are a few exceptions. for example: you can create an `audio` element using it's ctor

Comment: @ryan-cavanaugh , why doesn't TypeScript compile to `document.createElement`, instead of producing code which is known to not work? TS is all about trying to make JS useful and behave like a real programming language, right? Not being able to instantiate a class with `new`  does not seem very useful, neither intuitive nor productive. What prevents TypeScript from compiling  `new HTMLDivElement()` into `document.createElement('div')`? If the class can't be instantiated with `new`, it should be marked as being abstract or something like that, that would at least produce a compile time error.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't change the meaning of existing code.

Answer (score 39):

You have mistaken typescript syntax with c# syntax.

Just replace

```
var elem = new HTMLDivElement();
```

with one of the following

```
var elem = document.createElement('div');
```

or

```
var elem = <HTMLDivElement>(document.createElement('div'));
```

or

```
let elem = document.createElement('div') as HTMLDivElement
```

(if you need to use HTMLDivElement attributes)

Answer (score 11):

If you extend `HTMLElement` or any subclass like `HTMLDivElement`

You also need to register the custom element

```js
class SampleDiv extends HTMLDivElement{
    constructor(){
       super();
    }
}
customElements.define('sample-div', SampleDiv, { extends: 'div' });
```

See more here: 
https://javascript.info/custom-elements

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you need to add `{extends:'div'}` as the third argument to the define function: As in: `customElements.define('sample-div', SampleDiv, { extends: 'div' });`