# Trying to instantiate an HTMLElement extended class in native JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know we can use
`const a = document.createElement('a')`.

But what I'm trying is
`const a = new HTMLAnchorElement()`

However this will throw the following Exception :
`Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor`

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Where is `HTMLElement` extended at code at Question? Why are you trying to create an element using `HTMLAnchorElement`?

Comment: @guest271314 According to the specs, `HTMLAnchorElement` extends `HTMLElement` (`HTMLAnchorElement.prototype = new HTMLElement();`). Using an anchor in my post is to provide an example. I don't know it feels more right.

Comment: Not gathering what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @guest271314 really, there is no background to my question, I simply try to understand why trying to instantiate an HTMLElement won't work (because every HTML elements that can be bind to the dom are based on it) and I try to understand the behavior behind it, as I said it feels more right.

Comment: Speaking of ‘feel’,  I’ve always had the impression that the new keyword is loathed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instantiating new HTMLElement in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220243/instantiating-new-htmlelement-in-typescript)

Comment: Are you trying to use web components to create a custom element?

Comment: @guest271314 yes but this post has nothing to do with custom elements I think.

Comment: If custom elements is not within the scope of the inquiry is the question essentially why `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor` is thrown when trying to call `new HTMLAnchorElement()`?

Comment: @guest271314 yes but it is just not about `HTMLAnchorElement`, this exception is thrown on all the HTMLElement extended classes. I just pick one example. Also when creating a custom element we extend the HTMLElement base class and then we can use `new MyElement` to make one instance and append it in the dom, it will work. My question is *why won't that work using the native extended classes ?*

Comment: If you have read the [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#htmlconstructor) and not located the answer to your inquiry, consider  filing an [issue](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues) to attempt to get definitive clarification as to your question relevant to the current text of the specification.